# invoke a script on fail of a bash script

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I want to run a script  that create and host a website with apache server.
if anything went wrong I have to rollback all the changes I made, like delete the created folder etc.

I know `set -e` exits the script while detecting an error.

But what I need is **run a script, say rollback.sh, while detecting an error instead exiting**

Comment: Would `createSite.sh || rollback.sh` suffice?

Comment: I think this itself is the answer - he can accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the script, you can use `trap`:

```
err_handler () {
   /path/to/error/handling/script.sh
   exit
}

trap err_handler ERR
```

Since `ERR` is trapped, if any command exits with an non-zero exit code, `err_handler` function will be run.

You can think of `set -e` as doing this:

```
trap 'exit $?' ERR
```